# Html Selection Box to populate starting point as a middle value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am facing an issue when utilizing HTML selection box. I am wanting to have the starting point of the selection to be a middle value of the selection box input.

i.e. the selection box input values are "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"

and I want the starting to be "5"

How can I make this work?

Tank you kindly for your feedback

-matt

Comment: keep it 5,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10

Comment: Presumably the OP would like to keep the order 1..10

Answer (score 1):

Try  selected="selected" attribute in option tag

```
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option selected="selected">5</option>
<option>6</option>
<option>7</option>
<option>8</option>
<option>9</option>
<option>10</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `selected` attribute on option `5`

```
<select name="select">
  <option value="1">Value 1</option>
     ...
  <option value="5" selected>Value 5</option>
     ...
  <option value="10">Value 10</option>
</select>
```